# How can I add Twilio autopilot to the webchat

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Iam currently looking to build a scripted chat-bot for a website with twilio autopilot. Iam using 'Flex Webchat' for client side webchat interface.

Is it possible to add Autopilot in the beginning of a new chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can definitely include Autopilot in a chat like this. If you are using Studio to control your inbound Flex messages, then you can use the [Autopilot Studio Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/autopilot). Once the Autopilot interaction is complete (once the bot doesn't respond with `listen: true` in the actions) then the widget will complete and you can move on to wrap up the interaction or connect to a Flex agent.